# Why do some prices contain a sequence of a digit repeated several times?

Tags: pricing

I know about the psychology behind prices that end in 9 or 99, but I'm starting to notice that some prices contain the same digit (not 9) repeated two, three or even four times.

For example, in this week's leaflet a popular German supermarket is advertising tangerines for €1.11, plum tomatoes for €0.88 and onions for €0.66, but nearly all their other prices end with a 9. I remember seeing this pattern also in other circumstances, like a restaurant offering sandwiches for €7.77, and in phone rates.

What is the point of having prices like that? Do they make the product more interesting in any way?

Comment: Interesting observation. Perhaps there's a group of behavioral economists behind the scenes trying to study the effects repeating digits in prices on sales!

Comment: In marketing, I believe this is known as “charm pricing.” If you search under that name, you might find resources on that topic.